# How to extract ALL characters from a string to isolate the integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out a way to extract all characters from a string (`'.'`,`','`,`'abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz'`, `'/'`,`'\'`, etc...) and isolate the digits for instance:

if I have input:

```
hey.44.6 how a8re you99? -.23 4
```

My program needs to be able to extract each digit : `44`, `6`, `8`, `99`, `23` and `4` then give me the number of integers the string has (this one has 6) and the sum of the numbers.

I am having a really tough time even getting a start to this question, and I've looked at many options including `re`. If someone could help me even get a handle on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: It looks like you want to locate parts of your string that look like integers. "Extract all characters" is almost certainly not what you want to do. You have a sequence of all the characters right there - it's the string. Filtering your string to just the digits is also unuseful, since you'd lose the boundaries between numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `re`. Here's one way:

```
>>> re.findall("[0-9]+", s)
['44', '6', '8', '99', '23', '4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably faster than re:

```
def numbers_in_string(string):
    digitbuffer = ''
    for char in string:
        if char.isdigit():
            digitbuffer += char
        elif digitbuffer:
            yield int(digitbuffer)
            digitbuffer = ''
    if digitbuffer:
         yield int(digitbuffer)

>>> STRING = 'hey.44.6 how a8re you99? -.23 4'        
>>> print(list(numbers_in_string(STRING)))
[44, 6, 8, 99, 23, 4]
```